# Do Spectator Controls work while replaying a LOLReplay file?

Tags: league-of-legends

[League Replays](http://www.leaguereplays.com/) is by far the most famous replaying system for League of Legends, it has a nice set of controls like fast forwarding, slow motion and the imbued controls on the spectator mode are far more intuitive to use and more useful in my opinion.

Will a match recorded as a spectator using LOL Recorder enable the very same spectator controls as if on a Live Game when replayed later on?

Comment: Just remember how LoL replay works. It doesn't record the game, it basically just replays the game, which doesn't allow you to rewind or view health that you weren't watching during the actual game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now when I post this message, LoL Replay does not work with spectator mode. I have messed around with it to see what you can and cannot do with it, and the people who make LoL Replay are working on features that work like spectator mode, like a rewind and possibly a HUD that allows you to view who buys what/gold earned etc. but they have not announced a release date or an ETA as of yet. Just keep your eyes peeled to the site for whats going on :D

Comment: It's very complicated for them to implement all these features. In fact, if it does not change since the arrival of spec mode, LOReplay records what your client receive (an encrypted flow of data). And your client does not receive all the data of the game (cause you could make map hack etc if it was the case). So it's pretty difficult for them to make a spectator-like replay.